# Google Tables функция INDIRECT работает не так как хочу

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Для получения данных с другого листа использую функцию

**=INDIRECT("s!$A1")**
но обнаружил существенный недостаток: формула прописана на другом листе, и если лист, с которого будут получены данные, ещё не существует, то формула не работает, выдаёт ошибку что ссылается на недопустимый диапазон или лист. Если лист был создан заранее с нужным названием то всё корректно работает. Если лист создать, а потом переименовать, потом снова  вернуть прежнее имя, то тоже не работает.

**s** - это название листа

Нашёл временное решение, работает как надо, но оно тоже имеет недоработку

**=IMPORTRANGE("ссылка на файл"; "s!$A1")**
Тут идёт привязка к файлу. Этот вариант не подходит, так как при копировании файла, формулы должны оставаться рабочими, а так всё сломается.

Подскажите что можно придумать в таком случае.
Может есть вариант считывать имя файла чтоб подставить в **IMPORTRANGE** ?

Или есть ещё какая-то функция со схожими свойствами кроме **IMPORTRANGE** и **INDIRECT** ?

Нашёл ещё одно решение

**=query(s!A1;"select * limit 1")** , но... я не пойму как менять имя листа динамически. Нужно считывать имя с ячейки,(например имя **s** находится в ячейке F25), если я поменяю его (например на **g**) формула должна тоже измениться
**=query(g!A1;"select * limit 1")**

Comment: `=INDIRECT(A2&"!$A1")` - имя листа из ячейки. `=IF(ISERR(INDIRECT(A2&"!A2"));...` - проверка наличия листа

Comment: нет, не работает так. Я уже пробовал. Если лист ещё не создан то функция INDIRECT  не работает.

Comment: Работает только IMPORTRANGE и QUERY.
Но IMPORTRANGE привязана к файлу, а QUERY не может считывать имя листа из ячейки. Если  INDIRECT вложить внутрь QUERY то не работает то что мне нужно, это всё равно что пользоваться просто INDIRECT.

Comment: Провёл эксперимент сейчас. Функция QUERY не работает как надо! Похоже что только один вариант -  использовать IMPORTRANGE, нужно как-то вытянуть имя файла из ссылки, так как именно оно используется в функции https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/это_имя/edit#gid=1901460079

Comment: по моему вроде я нашёл решение  function GetSheetNameId() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
}   пробую....

Comment: первый раз долго загружает данные эта функция IMPORTRANGE. И всё равно как то странно работает. Не пойму почему если переименовать лист на, потом снова вернуть нужное имя - IMPORTRANGE не может получить также данные, если я их не обновлю в той ячейке или диапазоне на который она ссылается. Неужели нет способа просматривать что я хочу в реальном времени? Ведь по факту: лист есть, данные есть, а получить их не могу. Как это обойти? может как-нибудь делать Update формул на листе, или ещё что либо. странно вообще.

Comment: Наверное немного нестандартно я придумал, но так работает. И хочу исключить ошибки которые может допустить пользователь, неправильно создав лист. Или внести данные. Перепутать название, потом поменять... да пользователи что угодно могут придумать, хотел по максимуму обезопасить.

Comment: *Если лист ещё не создан то функция INDIRECT не работает.* - для чего я показал вариант с *ISSER*? `=IF(ISERR(INDIRECT(A2&"!A2"));"нет листа";INDIRECT(A2&"!A2"))`. А вообще: ссылаться на лист, которого еще нет - это костыльный вариант. Ищите нормальные пути решения проблемы (зависят от решаемой задачи)